# Why won't my Microsoft Test Manager Test Runs Generate Intellitrace Files?

Tags: .net, microsoft-test-manager, intellitrace

I am using Microsoft Test Manager 2010.  I have an application that I wish to test.  I have created a Test Configuration that has the "Intellitrace" option enabled.  I have created a test, which uses that configuration.  However, when I run the test and create a bug, I cannot find the Intellitrace, nor do I receive an error message.  Other items related to that configuration (i.e., Event Logs) do appear as expected.  What conditions could exist which are preventing me from successfully gathering the Intellitrace File?

Answer (score 0):

You must launch the application being tested from within the test case, and not attached to Visual Studio.  If you do not, the Test Manager will not be able to properly instrument the process, which must happen at process startup time.